# c# - Convert JSON to array

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm using Newtonsoft JSON.

```
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray userLists = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray.Parse(result)
MessageBox.Show((string)userLists[0]["name"]);
```

"result" contains:

> {"response":"1","0":{"id":"1","username":"bla","name":"bla
>   "},"1":{"id":"2","username":"blub","name":"blub"}}

What's wrong? The messagebox is empty and at index 1 it throws an error.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: userLists is not an array, it's an object with property names "response", "0" and "1" - either treat it like an object (so userLists.0.name) or format the JSON with [ ] to indicate that it's an array.

Comment: @Keith 
If I do this
MessageBox.Show((string)userLists.0.name);
the interpreter shows me errors like "invalid expression", even if I change "JArray" to "JObject".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON does not contain an array but rather an object. You can access it via the string index:

```
var o = JObject.Parse("{'response':'1','0':{'id':'1','username':'bla','name':'bla '},'1':{'id':'2','username':'blub','name':'blub'}}");
MessageBox.Show((string)o["0"]["name"]);
```

Comment: Oh, that's simple. ^^ Thank you.